# CodeIgniter Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have develop a website using CodeIgniter and Bootstrap

I have home.php and search.php

In home.php, I have a form to submit the word to be found, and post it to search.php,

and Bootstrap works fine in search.php, at this way

but I also have function in search.php which can be accessed within url

e.g. `mysite.com/search/with/words/`

and Bootstrap didn't works at this way

So much thank you before

Comment: mysite.com/search/with/words/ HERE search is the Controller, with is the Method and words is the Parameter, right? else you are not reading the codeigniter user guide

Comment: Yes, search.php is the controller, all the result work properly, only bootstrap not effect at the result

Comment: check your base_url in config file

Comment: the answer from Abdulla solved it, thank you Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question you can use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.js">
```

So file structer would be

```
1. application
2. system
3. assets
    - css
        1. bootstrap.css
    - js
        1. bootstrap.js
4. index.php
5. .htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, must use the `base_url()` to avoid wrong link location